# C# connecting to database error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, authentication, database-connection

I keep getting one issue while attempting to connect to a database. The database is supposed to allow remote connections, but for some reason it is not allowing the connection.

```
using MetroFramework;
using MetroFramework.Forms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ###WEBSITE###
{
public partial class Form1 : MetroForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=###WEBSITE###.com:3306;Initial Catalog=neoncheats_mybb;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from mybb_users where username = '" + Username.Text + "' and password = '" + Password.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            count += 1;
        }

        if (count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OK");
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            f1.Close();
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
        }
        else if (count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username and password");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or Password incorrect");
        }

        Password.Clear(); // Clears the password field
    }

    private void metroButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void metroLink1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://###WEBSITE###.com/Forum/member.php?action=lostpw");
    }
}
}
```

Notes:
The ###WEBSITE### is not actually there, I was removing the website's name.
The error comes from line 31 ( con.Open(); )
I have trued using a local database and got the same error with "localhost" being the domain

I know that my connection method isn't exactly ideal as well. I really need help with this as I am stumped and any help is appreciated!

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: You are trying to use this as your Data Source " ###WEBSITE###.com"? In reality the Data source looks like an IP. What error returns specifically?

Comment: I am using a web host with a port to direct the data to 3306 (sql port). Here is my error: https://gyazo.com/ca59ca1f4a423a1ae6db61ef09d48666 I tried to connect to the direct IP and I still get the same error

Comment: Have you tried to change Integrated Security to SSPI? And are you sure there is no credentials for that connection?

Comment: You are using winforms, sql connstring has website URL with port. Are you able to connect to this DB in SSMS or something ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to added UserId and Password..

look [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2016/) for connection string

Comment: I tried using a username and password as well but sadly I get the same error

Comment: The integrated security flag is set, as long as the account exists on the servers end and has access, he should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **Your-Datasource:3306;** , Try out using Data **Your-Datasource,3306;**

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure to always use a "Using" statement like below when the object supports the IDisposable interface:

```
using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    Conn.Open();
}
```

This ensures all of the objects you've created while in the block are properly disposed of (including your connection, you DB admin will find you).

Second, make sure "Data Source" is set to "Server" instead and that "Initial Catalog" are set to database.

"Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;"

See: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Hopefully that should help you get connected.

Answer (score 0):

For others experiencing this issue, I decided to use PHP to read the data from the database.

https://github.com/ThaisenPM/PHP-Database-Reader

Then just use webBrowser1.Document.TextContains to check if the data is correct